# Log.e() , Log.d() in ionic3?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

i want to get log like in android studio is using Log.d and Log.3 .Is there any way to do Log.e() and Log.d() in ionic? beside using console.log()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to debug as well as for error using console

```
console.log Black color text with no icon

console.info Blue color text with icon

console.debug Pure black color text

console.warn Yellow color text with icon

console.error Red Color text with icon

console.error() method writes an error message to the console.
console.info() method outputs an informational message to the console
console.warn() method outputs a warning message to the console
```

For more info check out the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_console.asp)

Comment: is the console.erorr write it's contain to txt file? or i should add in manually using native plugin from ionic?

Comment: it is like console.log you don't need to install any plugin